# Counting the number of times the next element in a vector is different to the previous one

Tags: r

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
a=c(rep(0,5),rep(1,5),rep(2,5))
b=c(rep(1,5),rep(1,5),rep(2,5))
d=rbind(a,b)

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
a    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1     1     2     2     2     2     2
b    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     2     2     2     2     2
```

What I want to do is count the number of times there is a change of a value across a row. For instance, on the first row, there are 2 changes one at column 5 to 6 and column 10 to 11.

I used an `if` statement and a `for` loop to compare each value and a counter `c` to count the number of times a changed occur:

```
m=matrix(NA, nrow = length(d[,1]), ncol = 1)

for (s in 1:length(d[,1])){

  c=0

  for (i in 1:length(d[1,])){

    if (i < length(d[1,])){

      if (d[s,i]!=d[s,(i+1)]){
        c=c+1
      }  

    }

  }

  m[s,1]<-c
}
```

At the end I have a matrix m with the number of switches on every row.
However, my data has thousands of rows and thousands of columns and this script is taking way too long to count the changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also try this:

```
apply(d,1,function(x) length(rle(x)$values)-1)
```

This function iterates through every row of the dataframe `d`. The iteration is done by `apply` and the second parameter (the margin) has the value 1 which indicates that rows should be selected (a margin of two would indicate columns).

So we apply the anonymous function `length(rle(x)$values)` to every row, which is temporarily stored in `x`. According to `help(rle)`, the `rle()` function does the following:

> Compute the lengths and values of runs of equal values in a vector

We are only interested in the values, and not in the length of the consecutive runs. But as a matter of fact, we don't even need to know the values, which are stored in `rle(x)$values`. The only thing that we care about here is *how many* values we have in the vector that constitute "runs of equal values". To extract the number of values, we can use the `length()` function, which determines the number of entries in a vector. Finally, since there is always at least one value and we want to know how often the value *changes* , we need to subtract 1 from the result obtained by `length()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the function does? As you can tell from the amount of `for` loops I use, I'm pretty new to R.

Comment: I'll add a text. Give me a few minutes :-)

Comment: Lovely explanation! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

use function `diff`

```
rowSums(t(apply(d,1,diff)))
```

or as suggested by Ben (not sure why I decided, `t` and `rowSums`)

```
colSums(apply(d,1,diff))
```

Again, I assumed the difference of "1" from example. but in case the numbers jump, you can try

```
colSums(apply(d,1,diff)!=0)
```

Comment: nice answer, but please flesh it out a little bit?  Why not `colSums(apply(d,1,diff))` ?  Note that this will *only* work if the diffs are always either 1 or 0 ...

Comment: OK, I applied it to my data and I'm sometimes getting -1. What would that mean when using `diff` ?

Answer (score 2):

And just for fun a solution with a **data.table** (*could* offer a better performance in case of huge data sizes - even though I don't think so in this case):

```
# Your original data
a=c(rep(0,5),rep(1,5),rep(2,5))
b=c(rep(1,5),rep(1,5),rep(2,5))
d=rbind(a,b)

# Solution starts here...
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(d)  # convert to data.table for high performance. "Performance penalty" here is that the matrix is copied completely (setDT does not work on a matrix)
cols <- ncol(dt)
diff <- dt[, 1:(cols-1), with=FALSE ] != dt[, 2:cols, with=FALSE ]  # find differences (TRUE/FALSE table as result)
rowSums(diff)       # sum the differences per row
```

results in

```
[1] 2 1
```

**How it works:**

I simply compare the two tables by "shifting" the columns by one which results in a table with TRUE/FALSE values where each TRUE indicates a change of the value compared to the next column:

```
> diff
        V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9  V10   V11   V12   V13   V14
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

No I can count the `TRUE`s (which have the value `1` in R, FALSE is `0` as you can find out with `as.numeric(TRUE)`).

PS: And yes, you could do the same without a data table (just compare the shifted matrix `d` ;-)